# Does the integral $\int_0^\infty \sin(2x^4) \, dx$ converge absolutely/conditionally?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

> Does the integral $$\int_0^\infty \sin(2x^4) \, dx$$ converge absolutely/conditionally?

I tried to evaluate $\int_0^b \sin(2x^4) dx$ by integrating by parts twice and got something relatively complicated, so I guess another way is preferable.

I also thought about using the Abel/Dirichlet test. Could it be applied here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via the substitution $2 x^4=u$, it can be shown that your integral is equivalent to
$$I=C\int_0^\infty \!du \,\frac{\sin u}{u^{3/4}} ,$$
with $C= 512^{-1/4}$.

Potential problems might arise for $u\to 0$ or for $u\to\infty$. So it is useful to split the integral in $I= C( I_1 + I_2)$ with
$$ I_1 = \int_0^\pi \!du \frac{\sin u}{u^{3/4}}$$
and 
$$ I_2= \int_\pi^\infty \!du \frac{\sin u}{u^{3/4}}.$$

For $u\to0$, we have that
$$ \frac{\sin u}{u^{3/4}} = O(u^{1/4})$$
so $I_1$ converges absolutely.

The integral $I_2$ is a bit more tricky. To test the absolute convergence, we need to estimate
$$ \int_\pi^\infty\!du\,\frac{|\sin u|}{u^{3/4}} 
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\!du\,\frac{|\sin u|}{u^{3/4}}\geq
 \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n\pi)^{-3/4} \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} |\sin u|
= \frac{2}{\pi^{3/4}} \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-3/4}$$
where we used the fact that $u^{-3/4}$ is monotonously decreasing. As $\sum n^{-3/4}$ diverges, the integral is not absolutely convergent.

On the other hand, we have that
$$ I_2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\!du\,\frac{\sin u}{u^{3/4}}\leq
 \sum_{n=1}^\infty ( (n+1)\pi)^{-3/4} \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} \sin u
= \frac{2}{\pi^{3/4}} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}(n+1)^{-3/4}$$
which converges because of the Dirichlet test. So the integral is in fact conditionally convergent.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain this: $\frac{\sin u}{u^{3/4}} = O(u^{1/4})$ and why is it implying $I_1$ converges absolutely?

Comment: @AlonAlon: the only problem for $I_1$ is the region around $u=0$. As $\sin u = u + \dots$, we have that $\sin /u^{3/4} = u^{1/4} + \dots$ so in fact the integrand in $I_1$ is bounded and you integrate over a finite interval.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's still unclear to me. What do you mean by "As $\sin u = u + \ldots$ we have that..."

Comment: @AlonAlon: the ... just indicates the Taylor series. If you think a bit about that, you will have no problems proving that $|\sin u/u^{3/4}| < C$ with $C$ some constant.

Comment: OK, thank you for your help @Fabian!

Comment: Cheers for this..I messed up the limits but even accounting for that, this is still the superior answer :) +1.

Comment: @k170: thanks...