# Proof of the convergence of $\int_0^\infty\sin{(x^4)} dx$ with Riemann-Lebesgue lemma

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, proof-explanation

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153083) question, a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153083/integral-int-0-infty-sinx4-dx?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment2351536_1153083) from [Lucian](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/93448/lucian) asserts that the convergence of the integral $$
I=\int_0^\infty\sin{(x^4)} dx
$$
is due to the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.
However, I don't immediately see how to apply this lemma.

I know that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{\infty} f(t)\sin(nt)dt = 0$$
whenever $f \in L^1(\Bbb R)$. Should I write $\sin{(x^4)}$ as a product, like $f(t)\sin(nt)$ ?

[By the way, a simplier way to see the convergence of the integral $I$ is that « the humps for $x\mapsto \sin(x^4)$ go up and down.  Each has an area smaller than that of the last.  The areas converge to $0$ as you progress down the $x$-axis.  By the alternating series test, this converges. » (adapted from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/105167) answer)].

Comment: very good question... i don't think riemann lebesgue is a good way to go here

Comment: @Watson I think he meant Dirichlet test for integral. Isn't it?

Comment: @OlivierOloa: this is possible. However, in Wikipedia, the integrals of such "oscillatory" functions can be proved to be convergent thanks to the Riemann–Lebesgue lemma, which "states that the integral of a function like the above is small. The integral will approach zero as the number of oscillations increases."

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106606/, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413950/

Comment: Let me have a look.

Comment: i am not an expert in the area, but heuritically it seems that the integrals subject to rl-lemma might be bounded by something like $C/n$ which would indeed can be used to show convergence of the integral in question

Comment: @Watson I don't see Riemann-Lebesgue there.

Comment: I think a direct way to prove convergence of the given integral is $x=u^{1/4}$ (as below) followed by integration by parts.

Comment: My point was similar to the one made by the user *NC Math Sadist*, whose answer you quoted, namely that the integrand basically tessellates itself into smithereens, much like in (but not identical to) the case of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.

Comment: @Lucian: ok, thank you. So this is not a _formal_ application of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, if I understand well.

Comment: Apparently not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the change of variable $x=u^{1/4}$, $dx=\dfrac14u^{-3/4}du$ you get
$$
\int_0^\infty\sin{(x^4)}dx=\frac14\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin{u}}{u^{3/4}}du
$$ then it is clearer how to apply the [Dirichlet test for integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141048/dirichlets-test-for-convergence-of-improper-integrals).

Comment: we still have to introduce a big parameter..how do we do this?

Comment: Thank you! Yes I know that Abel-Dirichlet's criterion applies, this is what I had in mind. But for Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, I don't see how to conclude.

Comment: @Watson You are welcome.